# Is there a way to return what percent of the data satisfies a set criteria?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image: data]

Can't really wrap around how to proceed with this. Its pretty straight forward - there are 33 observations for each variable and only 3 are not null in
*mean_sleep_time* and *mean_bed_time*.
All I want is a piece of code that returns *percentage of total* values.
In short a data-frame that shows *"out of 33 users only 3 have input valid data"*

Comment: Not sure what output you expect, since “out of 33 users only 3 have input valid data” is certainly *not* a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach :

```
library(dplyr) # for n_distinct

my_tot_user <- n_distinct(my_df$id)
my_df <- my_df[complete.cases(my_df),]
my_user <- n_distinct(my_df$id)
paste("out of ", my_tot_user, " users only ", my_user, " have input valid data", sep = "")
```

The function n_distinct allow us to get the number of unique value
The function complete.cases allow us to keep every row that doesn't contain any NA

Comment: Thanks, I usually never include it but I put it there just in case. I've removed it from the answer

Answer (score 0):

Short & sweet. Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, then:

`length(df[!is.na(df$mean_sleep_time&df$mean_bed_time),])/nrow(df)*100` for percentage

and

`length(df[!is.na(df$mean_sleep_time&df$mean_bed_time),])` for complete cases

`paste("Out of ", nrow(df), " users only ", length(df[!is.na(df$mean_sleep_time&df$mean_bed_time),]), " have valid input data", sep = "")`